# Hide Bottom Tab bar when Admob ad is opened in iphone

Tags: ios, admob

i am using Admob in my app. I am placing Admob just above the Bottom Tab bar. Now when i click on the ad, the ads are opened. but the bottom tab bar appears for some of the ads. I want to get rid of it.

Basically when i click on the Ad, the bottom bar should be hidden. So how do i get notified when the Ad is clicked or is any other way we can achieve this?Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout these two delegate methods of `GADBannerViewDelegate`  do your stuff in these methods

```
  - (void)adViewWillPresentScreen:(GADBannerView *)bannerView;
  - (void)adViewWillLeaveApplication:(GADBannerView *)bannerView;
```

[Here is full docs](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/intermediate#ios-gadbannerviewdelegate)